# How to merge tab delimited files by key and add tabs to each file?

Tags: python, database, bash, merge, python-requests

I have a number of tab delimited files that share a common key. I need to merge them by that key, and ensure that a specified number of trailing empty columns are preserved. Each file has a different number of rows.

Each file has a specified number of columns, and many of the files have the trailing columns blank. For example file 1 should have 30 columns.

```
1 MQTW 2020-10-99
2 HTVR 1965-02-17 PM
```

And file 2 should have 500 columns

```
1 TLPRTY 22 M 7 9 ....
2 JAOSKQM 54  9 T ....
```

I want to make sure the defined number of columns in each file is preserved. The sample result should look as follows, with the blank 26 columns from file 1 kept in between file 1 and file 2 contents

```
1 MQTW 2020-10-99     .... TLPRTY 22 M 7 9 ....
2 HTVR 1965-02-17 PM  .... JAOSKQM 54  9 T ....
```

I’d be open to a solution in Python or Bash, thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `pandas` [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for this

Comment: *How* should they be merged? Please provide sample results.

Comment: @Shawn I've updated the question with sample results

Comment: If the files are sorted on the first column like you sample, look into `join`.

Comment: Pandas is the right tool if python works for you. You can also use the bash join utility, but the solution will be more complicated to implement